# "TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'" in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

```
disbursementData_dropped = disbursementData.drop_duplicates(
        [
            "form_field_1",
            "portfolio_name",
            "initial_application_category_name",
            "disbursement_amount",
        ],
        keep="last",
        ignore_index=True,
    )
```

I'm new to Python and PANDAS and I'm trying to run a larger script that's been maintained with my company for several years that generates a CSV with information. However, whenever I try to run it I get the error in the title, and I have minimal PANDAS experience so I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `ignore_index` was added in pandas version 1.0.0 so you are probably running an older version of pandas in your env. What is returned when you do `print(pandas.__version__)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris i believe this is version 0.24.2. i also think this was written in Python 2

Comment: Since the script had been maintained by your company and who ever wrote it used pandas >= 1.0.0. So, I have to assume there is a virtual environment on the server than can run this script.

Answer (score 0):

[Drop_duplicate description file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

If you can provide a slice of your data or fabricate data, that will be much helpful.

But I attached the drop_duplicates link here for your reference.